# Multiple parallax video backgrounds

Tags: video, background, parallax

I found answers here on stackoverflow on how to create video div with parallax effect
The recommended plugin was:
https://github.com/linnett/backgroundVideo

However I need multiple of parallax backgrounds on one site and I am having trouble with that, first one in order is allright, but the others are misspositioned, dont work absolutely as you would expect

What is a solution for this? Calling the same plugin for every background separately?
How do I do that?

This doesnt quite work:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#my-video").backgroundVideo();
    $("#my-video2").backgroundVideo();
  });
</script>
```

This is HTML of video element:

```
<div id="video-wrap" style="height: 300px;">
  <video id="my-video" preload="metadata" autoplay loop>
    <source src="blahblah/video/video1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i figuerd out the solution

You have to have differend video wrap ID for each of parallax video you want to display and then specify it in JS

HTML:

```
<div id="video-wrap1" class="video">
  <video id="my-video1" preload="metadata" autoplay loop>
    <source src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/video/video1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>

<div id="video-wrap2" class="video">
  <video id="my-video2" preload="metadata" autoplay loop>
    <source src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/video/video1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
...
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#my-video1").backgroundVideo({$videoWrap: $('#video-wrap1')});
$("#my-video2").backgroundVideo({$videoWrap: $('#video-wrap2')});
...
```

Works as charm :)

Comment: For some reason, I'm having an issue where if I use a class name to initiate the backgroundVideo() it works fine, but when using IDs like you do to solve the multiple instance issue, they do not initialize. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The plugin has been updated to allow for multiple videos, check the example use: https://github.com/linnett/backgroundVideo